# How to declare an operator with automatic argument bracketing

Tags: math-operators, delimiters

I'd like to have an easy way to declare an operator that brackets its argument with a particular delimiter. As an example I'd like to be able to write

```
\Pr{X}
```

to mean the same as

```
\operatorname{Pr}\left[X\right]
```

FYI I know how to do

```
\newcommand{\Pr}[1]{\operatorname{Pr}\left[#1\right]}
```

but I thought I once saw a package that provided some command like

```
\DeclareBracketedOperator{\Pr}{Pr}{[}{]}
```

sort of a combination of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` and `\DeclareMathOperator` and I think it also defined a starred version of the operator that didn't take any argument and didn't produce the delimiters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't remember of any such package. Your `\Pr` command maybe obtained by

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Prfences}{[}{]}
\renewcommand{\Pr}{\operatorname{Pr}\Prfences}
```

With this definition, `\Pr` would behave exactly as if it was defined with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`; that is, the `*`-form would use `\left` and `\right`.

If you want to always use `\left` and `\right`, you might follow Werner's suggestion, or go the hard way:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Pr}{\operatorname{Pr}\@ifstar\@firstofone\@Pr}
\newcommand{\@Pr}[1]{\left[#1\right]}
\makeatother
```

(requires **amsmath**, of course). Note: `\renewcommand{\Pr}{...}` is necessary, because `\Pr` is already defined in LaTeX.

Comment: Is there a way to redeclare existing operators such as `\ln` to use delimiters as well?

Comment: @math Just do `\renewcommand{\ln}{\operatorname{ln}\Prfences}`. But the logarithm doesn't want delimiters: `\log x` is the best way to write it.

Comment: I have the equation by Stejskal and Tanner: $\ln{A(t)} = \ln{A(0)} - bg^TTg$ But when you deal with summation and `\ln` I want to separate the argument of `\ln` from the summands. Clearly I could rewrite it to $\ln{A(t)-\ln{A(0)} = - bg^TTg$, but the problem to separate the logarithm expression from summands may remain. So can you comment further on that, why log dislikes delimiters?

Comment: @math Add the delimiters; I don't think you get a clearer input with `$\log{A(t)}$` than with `$\log(A(t))$`.

Comment: don't get me wrong. I just asked as to get more insight not to be too picky. I thought about `\log[A(0)] - bg^TTg`.

Comment: @math In the case of the present question, `\Pr` is wanted to always have the same pair of delimiters. In the case of `\log`, as you show, there's not this need.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a way to define your own operator with an optional bracketing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\Pr}{s m}{% \Pr[*]{..}
  \operatorname{Pr}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}% Condition on *
    {#2}% Print only the argument in starred * version
    {\left[#2\right]}% Print bracketed argument [ ] in unstarred version
}%
\begin{document}

This is $\Pr{2}$, and here is
\[
  \Pr{\frac{\frac{a}{b+c}}{d-e}}=\Pr*{\frac{8}{9}}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Operator with starred version that brackets/doesn't bracket argument]

The above code defines the macro `\Pr{..}` (actually redefines `\Pr`, since it is provided by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)), but also provides a starred `*` version. The unstarred version, as requested, prints its argument in extensible brackets, while the starred `*` version removes these brackets.

The [`xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides an easy interface to specify starred versions of commands and environments. The `xifthen` package provides conditional support.