# Defining macros with arguments

Tags: macros

With `newcommand` I can define customized command like `\ABC`. Is there any way to define a command with arguments. For example I want `\brat{A}{B}` be the same as `[\![A,B]\!]`.

Comment: Just to make sure: You want use to round parentheses and one comma (and no spaces) to set off the two parameters?

Comment: No, I want to feed the arguments, I don't know how.

Comment: So would `\brat{A}{B}` be acceptable syntax?

Comment: `\newcommand\ABC[3]{Something with #1, #2 and #3}` where the number is the number of parameters.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28042/how-to-declare-an-operator-with-automatic-argument-bracketing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The general form of `\newcommand` is

```
\newcommand\commandname[number of arguments][value of optional argument]{code}
```

(Most of the time there won't be an optional argument, in which case this is omitted.) The arguments are given as `#1`, `#2` etc in `code`.

To define your `\brat` command you would write

```
\newcommand\brat[2]{[\![#1,#2]\!]}
```

You then use this macro by writing `\brat{A}{B}`, `\brat{A}{C}` and so on. If almost all of the time you wanted the first argument to be `A` then you could instead use an optional first argument and define

```
\newcommand\Brat[2][A]{[\![#1,#2]\!]}
```

You use this version of the macro n almost exactly the same way except that you do not need to specify `A`: so `\Brat{B}` produces the same as `\brat{A}{B}` before. To change the value of the optional argument from `A` to `C`, say, you would write `\Brat[C]{B}`. This is the same as `\brat{C}{B}` using the first macro.

Answer (score 1):

In TeX, we can define macros with arguments by

```
 \def\macro#1#2#3#4{body with #1 argument, #2 argument, #3 argument, #4 argument}
```

and usage is:

```
 \macro{first}{second}{third}{four}
```

or

```
\macro fstf
```

which is equivalent to `\macro{f}{s}{t}{f}`.

There is another method to declaring "delimited" parameters (which is not supported by LaTeX `\newcommand`), see (for example) [TeX in a Nutshell](http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf), pages 9 and 10.