# How to refer to indexed words

Tags: macros, hyperref, cross-referencing, indexing, cleveref

Given a text with an indexed word, say `minimum`, is it possible to have a command, call it `\DEX{}`, that would print a later occurrence of that word and link it to the original occurrence? For an on-screen pdf, this would allow the reader to bypass the index by just clicking on the word s/he wants to check while `\Cpageref{minimum}`(`\Cpageref{index:minimum}`?) would allow the reader similarly to bypass the index on a printed copy.

Could this work with a word defined in a `tcolorbox`? In my case, though, this would be icing on the cake because, the magnum opus being written for raw beginners, most words are not formally defined, only a very few are. Besides, I already use `cleveref` for that. So, just asking.

Here is a MWE (Not quite minimum because I need the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx and I included a tcolorbox just in case someone wants to try it.)

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{book}  
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \makeindex
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
%==================Begin HYPERREF
    \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%[pdfborder={0 0 0}]

%Begin the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%End the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx

    \usepackage{cleveref}
%Begin the Sharpe code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1)            
\let\oldopenparen\(
\let\oldcloseparen\)
\def\({\protect\oldopenparen}
\def\){\protect\oldcloseparen}
\newcommand{\INDEX}[1]{\index{#1}}
%End the Sharpe code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1)          

\newcounter{abc}%
\newtcolorbox%
[%beginForReferences
use counter= abc,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitleagree},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
crefname={definition}{definitions},
Crefname={Definition}{Definitions},
]%endForReferences
{greement}
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
coltitle=black,
nameref={#2},%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
code={\gdef\mytitleagree{#2}},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
title=DEFINITION \thetcbcounter,%
#1,%Required for references.
}%


    \begin{document}

A \textbf{minimum}\INDEX{minimum} of a function is blah blah.

\begin{greement}[label={abc:3-1}]{Maximum}
  An input whose output is larger than the outputs of nearby inputs
\end{greement}


\newpage

A function can have more than one $\backslash$DEX\{minimum\} ($\backslash$Cpageref\{minimum\}.)


(The command $\backslash$DEX would print  the word minimum and link it to the above occurrence. Hopefully, $\backslash$Cpageref would still work too.)

\printindex
    \end{document}
```

and here is the pdf (without `\newpage` and without the index page). Note the swhowidx on the upper right:

[image]

Comment: Isn't this something for a glossary?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not sure what you mean. The idea is to _bypass_ the index: instead of 1. looking up `minimum` in the index and then 2. clicking on the page number `1`, why not _just click_ on the later occurrence of `minimum`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I don't understand what you want to do but it seems to me that all you need to do is to make your `\INDEX` command add a `\label{...}` for your index entry and then your `\DEX` command refers back to it. As you want to make a link in the PDF file you should use `\hyperref` from the [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package to create this link, rather than `\ref`. For good measure, the `\DEX` should also insert the `\Cpageref` command.

Putting this together, your `\INDEX` and `\DEX` commands become:

```
\newcommand{\INDEX}[1]{\index{#1}\label{ind:#1}}
\newcommand\DEX[1]{\hyperref[ind:#1]{#1} (\Cpageref{ind:#1})}
```

I have made the automatically generated index `\label`'s of the form `ind:...` so that they are less likely to conflict with other labels.

With this is place, here is the output on page 2, showing the mouse-over that's over the word *minimum*:

[image]

(I use skim to view PDFs and one of its many great features is this mouse-over. Acrobat, for example, doesn't do this.)

**EDIT**

As noted in the comments, this approach goes wrong when indexing mathematics, such as `\INDEX{$\pm$}`. This really isn't surprising because having mathematics inside an index or label key is almost certain to cause problems but this means that to cope with cases like these we need to be able to manually override the label that is being used. This is most easily done using the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package that allows use to define `\INDEX` and `\DEX` as

```
\NewDocumentCommand\INDEX{ O{#2} m}{\index{#2}\label{ind:#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand\DEX{ O{#2} m }{\hyperref[ind:#1]{#2} (\Cpageref{ind:#1})}
```

What this means is that `\INDEX` now has an optional argument, which defaults to the value of the second argument, that is used in the labels. So, to index `$\pm$` we can now type

```
\INDEX[pm]{$\pm$}
```

Similarly, the `\DEX` also accepts an optional argument, so to refer to $\pm$ we would use `\DEX[pm]{$\pm$}`. We only need top use the optional arguments to `\INDEX` and `\DEX` if what we are indexing is "complicated" in some way, such as in mathematics mode, and otherwise we use these two macros as before.

[Incidentally, `\newcommand` also caters for optional arguments (see [Defining macros with arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191266/defining-macros-with-arguments/191271#191271)). The only reason that  have used `\NewDocumentCommand` is that is has an easier mechanism for dealing with default values.]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \makeindex
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
%==================Begin HYPERREF
    \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%[pdfborder={0 0 0}]

%Begin the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%End the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx

    \usepackage{cleveref}
%Begin the Sharpe code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1)
\let\oldopenparen\(
\let\oldcloseparen\)
\def\({\protect\oldopenparen}
\def\){\protect\oldcloseparen}
%End the Sharpe code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1)

\newcommand{\INDEX}[2][]{%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\index{#2}\label{ind:#2}%
   \else\index{#2}\label{ind:#1}\fi%
}
\newcommand{\DEX}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\hyperref[ind:#2]{#2} (\Cpageref{ind:#2})%
   \else\hyperref[ind:#1]{#2} (\Cpageref{ind:#1})\fi%
}

\newcounter{abc}%
\newtcolorbox%
[%beginForReferences
use counter= abc,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitleagree},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
crefname={definition}{definitions},
Crefname={Definition}{Definitions},
]%endForReferences
{greement}
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
coltitle=black,
nameref={#2},%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
code={\gdef\mytitleagree{#2}},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
title=DEFINITION \thetcbcounter,%
#1,%Required for references.
}%



    \begin{document}

A \textbf{minimum}\INDEX{minimum} of a function is blah blah.

\begin{greement}[label={abc:3-1}]{Maximum}
  An input whose output is larger than the outputs of nearby inputs
\end{greement}

\INDEX[pm]{$\pm$}
\newpage

A function can have more than one \DEX{minimum}.

A function can have more than one \DEX{minimum}.

\chapter{one} \textbf{Andy}\INDEX[]{Andy} \chapter{two} \textbf{Beth}\INDEX[]{Beth} \chapter{three} \textbf{Carla}\INDEX[]{Carla} \chapter`{four}` \DEX[]{Andy} \DEX[]{Beth} \DEX[]{Carla}.

\printindex


    \end{document}
```

Comment: I agree but isn't using `\label` superfluous? After all, the reference is already in the `.idx` file, namely `\indexentry{minimum|hyperpage}{1}`. So, DEX ought to be able to use it like a sort of `nameref`. (But I don't know how to do that.)

Comment: @schremmer nI theory, yes, one could extract the reference from the index but doing this would be slightly painful because I'm fairy sure that no one has provided a mechanism for doing this. More importantly, the hyperlinks from the index point *only* to page numbers rather than to the actual reference on the page whereas `\label{...}` and `\ref{...}` give fairly precise hyperlinks. Given this, I think that constructing an extra `\ref{...}` is worth doing.

Comment: Now I understand why you wrote "_Perhaps I don't understand what you want to do ..._": modifying my `\INDEX`command to include a `\label` was of course the obvious way to go. Which goes to show that I don't know anything about LaTeX--which _I_ well know. But I like to understand which is why I asked the question you just answered. I am most grateful for the explanation. Still, in these days of live links, someone ought to suggest to Heiko Oberdieck to upgrade the index. But _I_ am happy.

Comment: A curio: `\INDEX{$x_{0}$}` and `\label{ind:$x_{0}$}` both work but while `\INDEX{$\pm$}` works, `\label{ind:$\pm$}` causes `Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \pm 
l.120 ...$\pm $}{{1.2.3}{4}{}{subsection.1.2.3}{}}
                                                  
? 
`.

Comment: @schremmer I would *never* use math-mode inside a reference, which is why this is failing here, but I guess with your use-case this is problematic. I would make `\INDEX` and `\DEX` both take an optional argument that allows you to set the label "manually" in cases like these where you are indexing mathematics. I'll edit the post to do this.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long but I had a hard time nailing down the problem. To see it, just use as your document `\chapter{one}` `\textbf{Andy}\INDEX[]{Andy}` `\chapter{two}` `\textbf{Beth}\INDEX[]{Beth}` `\chapter{three}` `\textbf{Carla}\INDEX[]{Carla}` `\chapter{four}` `\DEX[]{Andy}` `\DEX[]{Beth}` `\DEX[]{Carla}`, `\printindex`. You will see that while the `Index` links correctly Andy to page 1,  Beth to page 3 and Carla to page 5, the references on page 7 are all to page 5.

Comment: @schremmer Sorry, silly question: what's your compilation procedure? I a not seeing the index at all. I used `pdflatex`, `makeindex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`...

Comment: Sorry, silly answer: I don't know. Here is what I found: 1. Your _full code_ has the error `\INDEX{minimum}` and `\DEX{minimum}` (without `[]`) 2. My original code above does not print the Index either,  3. With `% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk` as first line, both my original code and your _full code_ give the index (???), 4. TeXShop tells me that I am compiling with LaTeX with Pdftex as "default script". Hope this helps.

Comment: @schremmer For some reason the optional arguments for `\INDEX` and `\DEX` were not working (perhaps I misunderstand what it says in the `xparse` manual...). I have fixed this now and everything seems to work including the links in the index.

Comment: 1. Everything OK with Andy, Beth, Carla, with or without the latexmark line. 2. **EVERYTHING** OK WITH THE MAGNUM OPUS as well, with mathematics in and out of tcolorboxes. But I really wanted to check because of the particular file structure I am using to avoid `\includeonly`. 3. Re. `\phantomsection` things are actually even more complicated. If you are interested, compare `Text-controls/1.tex` (no `\phantomsection`) with `Text-controls/ALL.tex`(a `\phantomsection`) in (http://freemathtexts.org/BU/RAFv7-1-3text.zip) Well, I think that's it and I am MOST grateful, if only for your patience.

Comment: @schremmer The problem that I fixed with the optional arguments also fixed the links in the index, so the `\panthomsection` command can be removed. I don't understand why the optional arguments did not work before but I have done them "by hand" now so they are OK.

Comment: Things are working very, very nicely but I found another "curio": `\INDEX[]{Indexed word}` at the beginning of a line causes the error `Undefined control sequence.
\HyInd@showidx ...#1}\if@nobreak \ifvmode \nobrak 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.599 \INDEX[]{indexed word}`but that's easily fixed with  `\hspace{0mm}\INDEX[]{Indexed word}` which works fine. I hadn't noticed until now because this was the first time `\INDEX{indexed word}` was not preceded by something. I just thought someone else using the code might want to know.