# Reference in a box to an indexed word

Tags: macros, hyperref, cleveref, soul

In [highlighting math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318991/highlighting-math), JPi defined `\hlfancy` a breakable box to highlight text involving `math`.

In [How to refer to indexed words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393821/how-to-refer-to-indexed-words), Andrew defined `\INDEX` and `\DEX` to refer to indexed words which work fine when the reference is in a `tcolorbox` or in a `\colorbox` but not in a `\hlfancy` box where it causes an error.

To see, uncomment `%\hlfancy{yellow}{A reference in an hlfancybox: \DEX[aaaa]{aaaC}}` in the following minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%Begin breakable hlfancy boxes. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318991/highlighting-math
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\mathcolorbox}[2]{\colorbox{#1}{$\displaystyle #2$}}
\newcommand{\hlfancy}[2]{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}
%End breakable hlfancy boxes.

    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \makeindex
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
%==================Begin HYPERREF
    \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%[pdfborder={0 0 0}]

%Begin the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%End the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx

    \usepackage{cleveref}
%Begin the Sharpe code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1)
\let\oldopenparen\(
\let\oldcloseparen\)
\def\({\protect\oldopenparen}
\def\){\protect\oldcloseparen}
%End the Sharpe code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1)
%Begin referring code
\newcommand{\INDEX}[2][]{%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\index{#2}\label{ind:#2}%
   \else\index{#2}\label{ind:#1}\fi%
}
\newcommand{\DEX}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\hyperref[ind:#2]{#2} (\Cpageref{ind:#2})%
   \else\hyperref[ind:#1]{#2} (\Cpageref{ind:#1})\fi%
}%
%End referring code
\newcounter{abc}%
\newtcolorbox%
[%begin code for tcolorbox
use counter= abc,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitleagree},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
crefname={definition}{definitions},
Crefname={Definition}{Definitions},
]%endForReferences
{greement}
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
coltitle=black,
nameref={#2},%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
code={\gdef\mytitleagree{#2}},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
title=DEFINITION \thetcbcounter,%
#1,%Required for references.
}%
%End code for  tcolor box
\makeindex
\begin{document}

A word \textbf{aaaa}\INDEX[aaaa]{aaaa} in some text 

\begin{greement}[label={abc:3-1}]{Title}
A reference \DEX[aaaa]{aaaA} in a tcolorbox 
\end{greement}

\colorbox{yellow}{A reference in a colorbox: \DEX[aaaa]{aaaB}}

%\hlfancy{yellow}{A reference in an hlfancybox: \DEX[aaaa]{aaaC}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am the other schremmer but I do not know how to rectify my error.

Comment: @Cragfelt: It is the same user named schremmer `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393821/how-to-refer-to-indexed-words` but logged in as other user... don't ask why

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Here is how if not why: I forgot to enter my password and StackExchange created a new account with the same name and same email address. No idea how to correct things. I wish I could.

Comment: @schremmer: Please contact the SE staff in ask them about a merging of your accounts then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have no idea how to do this. Could you point me in the right direction or would it be better for me to remove this and redo it from scratch?

Comment: Thank you Christian. @schremmer you can merge both accounts as it is specified here https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @Cragfelt As you can see, done deed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation of soul: Some things don't work. If you want to use such command inside a soul command you must hide them inside a \mbox. And yes this prevents line breaks for this command and so is not a solution for longer texts:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%Begin breakable hlfancy boxes. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318991/highlighting-math
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\mathcolorbox}[2]{\colorbox{#1}{$\displaystyle #2$}}
\newcommand{\hlfancy}[2]{\sethlcolor{#1}\hl{#2}}
%End breakable hlfancy boxes.

    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \makeindex
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
%==================Begin HYPERREF
    \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%[pdfborder={0 0 0}]

%Begin the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%End the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx

    \usepackage{cleveref}
%Begin the Sharpe code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1)
\let\oldopenparen\(
\let\oldcloseparen\)
\def\({\protect\oldopenparen}
\def\){\protect\oldcloseparen}
%End the Sharpe code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1)
%Begin referring code
\newcommand{\INDEX}[2][]{%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\index{#2}\label{ind:#2}%
   \else\index{#2}\label{ind:#1}\fi%
}
\newcommand{\DEX}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\hyperref[ind:#2]{#2} (\Cpageref{ind:#2})%
   \else\hyperref[ind:#1]{#2} (\Cpageref{ind:#1})\fi%
}%
%End referring code
\newcounter{abc}%
\newtcolorbox%
[%begin code for tcolorbox
use counter= abc,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitleagree},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
crefname={definition}{definitions},
Crefname={Definition}{Definitions},
]%endForReferences
{greement}
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
coltitle=black,
nameref={#2},%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
code={\gdef\mytitleagree{#2}},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
title=DEFINITION \thetcbcounter,%
#1,%Required for references.
}%
%End code for  tcolor box
\makeindex


\begin{document}

A word \textbf{aaaa}\INDEX[aaaa]{aaaa} in some text

\begin{greement}[label={abc:3-1}]{Title}
A reference \DEX[aaaa]{aaaA} in a tcolorbox
\end{greement}

\colorbox{yellow}{A reference in a colorbox: \DEX[aaaa]{aaaB}}

\hlfancy{yellow}{A reference in an hlfancybox: \mbox{\DEX[aaaa]{aaaC}}}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fisher Of course it doesn't break inside the `mbox`---so maybe you should change your wording above, but it sure does exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: A lot of people complain later that text doesn't break in a box, so I thought it would better to say it directly.

Comment: I meant that, since it doesn't not prevent the rest of the text in the `hlfancy box` from breaking, I would add "in the `mbox`" to "
this prevents ... longer texts". But then, that's just me and, anyway, it worked fine for me. Thanks again.