# Distinguish forward cross-references from backward cross-references

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, tcolorbox, cleveref

Andrew gave an answer to the question in [How to refer to indexed words](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393821/how-to-refer-to-indexed-words) (which is working *very, very nicely*). As it happens, it allows referring `forward` to where the word will be defined as well as the usual `backward`. This is actually very helpful as when explaining at the beginning of a chapter what will be done, but would be even more helpful if one could differentiate `forward` from `backward`, say with a different `hyperref color`. Here is the MWF that Andrew answered modified to use `hyperref color` instead of boxes and with a reference `forward`.

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{book}
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \makeindex
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
%==================Begin HYPERREF
    \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%[pdfborder={0 0 0}]

%Begin the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%End the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
    \hypersetup{%begin colors
                   colorlinks,
                   linkcolor={red!50!black},
                   citecolor={blue!50!black},
                  urlcolor={blue!80!black}
                }%end colors

    \usepackage{cleveref}
%Begin the Sharpe code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1)
\let\oldopenparen\(
\let\oldcloseparen\)
\def\({\protect\oldopenparen}
\def\){\protect\oldcloseparen}
%End the Sharpe code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1)

\newcommand{\INDEX}[2][]{%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\index{#2}\label{ind:#2}%
   \else\index{#2}\label{ind:#1}\fi%
}
\newcommand{\DEX}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\hyperref[ind:#2]{#2} (\Cpageref{ind:#2})%
   \else\hyperref[ind:#1]{#2} (\Cpageref{ind:#1})\fi%
}%

\newcounter{abc}%
\newtcolorbox%
[%beginForReferences
use counter= abc,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitleagree},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
crefname={definition}{definitions},
Crefname={Definition}{Definitions},
]%endForReferences
{greement}
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
coltitle=black,
nameref={#2},%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
code={\gdef\mytitleagree{#2}},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
title=DEFINITION \thetcbcounter,%
#1,%Required for references.
}%



    \begin{document}

A \textbf{minimum}\INDEX{minimum} of a function is blah blah.

And here is a reference ahead: \DEX[]{Carla}

\begin{greement}[label={abc:3-1}]{Maximum}
  An input whose output is larger than the outputs of nearby inputs
\end{greement}

\INDEX[pm]{$\pm$}
\newpage

A function can have more than one \DEX{minimum}.

A function can have more than one \DEX{minimum}.

\chapter{one} \textbf{Andy}\INDEX[]{Andy} \chapter{two} \textbf{Beth}\INDEX[]{Beth} \chapter{three} \textbf{Carla}\INDEX[]{Carla} \chapter`{four}` \DEX[]{Andy} \DEX[]{Beth} .

\printindex


    \end{document}
```

So, my question is: how can `forward cross-references` be made made to look different from `backward cross-references`?

Comment: Is there a question in here, or is this a neat feature that you've added to a different answer?  If the latter, I like that this example exists, but I don't think a "question" is the proper place for it.

Comment: @Teepeemm I had thought that by saying that _ it would be even more helpful if one could differentiate `ahead` from `back`_ I had acknowledged that I had  _not_ been able to implement this "neat feature". Also, it is _not_ in the MWE. I have edited my post to specifically ask for help in adding the feature.

Comment: @schremmer: By the way, you have some questions with unaccepted answers...

Comment: @Hupfer I will try to find them because I don't like to do that. Any hint would be helpful though.

Comment: [Re](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410362/distinguish-forward-cross-references-from-backward-cross-references#comment1024374_410362), you can search for [`user:me hasaccepted:0 answers:1..`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15042+hasaccepted%3A0+answers%3A1..).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as only the `\DEX` macro is used in order to generate references to the linked words, there is a quite simple way to distinguish between forward and backward links:

Check for the current page number and compare with the page reference of the linked word with `\ifnum\value{page} > \getpagerefnumber{ind:#2}...\else...\fi`.

In the first case we have a back reference, in the second case we have a forward reference, for references on the same page this will not work (yet), I will try to update later on (i.e. tomorrow) with a better version)

I've provided two new colors: `forwardlinkcolor` and `backwardlinkcolor`, change their definitions at will.

```
\newcommand{\DEX}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \ifnum\value{page} > \getpagerefnumber{ind:#2}%
  \hypersetup{%
    linkcolor=backwardlinkcolor
  }%
  \else
  \hypersetup{%
    linkcolor=forwardlinkcolor
  }%
  \fi
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\hyperref[ind:#2]{#2} (\Cpageref{ind:#2})%
  \else\hyperref[ind:#1]{#2} (\Cpageref{ind:#1})\fi%
  \endgroup
}%
```

The full code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
% ==================Begin HYPERREF
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%[pdfborder={0 0 0}]

%Begin the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%End the ``quick and dirty hack'' due to Heiko Oberdiek which loads showidx
\hypersetup{%begin colors
  colorlinks,
  linkcolor={red!50!black},
  citecolor={blue!50!black},
  urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}%end colors

\usepackage{cleveref}
%Begin the Sharpe code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1)
\let\oldopenparen\(
\let\oldcloseparen\)
\def\({\protect\oldopenparen}
\def\){\protect\oldcloseparen}
%End the Sharpe code as modified by Schulz (2016-02-1)

\newcommand{\INDEX}[2][]{%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\index{#2}\label{ind:#2}%
   \else\index{#2}\label{ind:#1}\fi%
}

\colorlet{forwardlinkcolor}{red!50!black}
\colorlet{backwardlinkcolor}{green!40!blue}

\newcommand{\DEX}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
  \ifnum\value{page} > \getpagerefnumber{ind:#2}%
  \hypersetup{%
    linkcolor=backwardlinkcolor
  }%
  \else
  \hypersetup{%
    linkcolor=forwardlinkcolor
  }%
  \fi
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\hyperref[ind:#2]{#2} (\Cpageref{ind:#2})%
  \else\hyperref[ind:#1]{#2} (\Cpageref{ind:#1})\fi%
  \endgroup
}

\newcounter{abc}%
\newtcolorbox%
[%beginForReferences
use counter= abc,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitleagree},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
crefname={definition}{definitions},
Crefname={Definition}{Definitions},
]%endForReferences
{greement}
[2][]%
{%
detach title,
coltitle=black,
nameref={#2},%
before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
code={\gdef\mytitleagree{#2}},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
title=DEFINITION \thetcbcounter,%
#1,%Required for references.
}%



\begin{document}

A \textbf{minimum}\INDEX{minimum} of a function is blah blah.

And here is a reference ahead: \DEX[]{Carla}

\begin{greement}[label={abc:3-1}]{Maximum}
  An input whose output is larger than the outputs of nearby inputs
\end{greement}

\INDEX[pm]{$\pm$}
\newpage

A function can have more than one \DEX{minimum}.

A function can have more than one \DEX{minimum}.

\chapter{one} \textbf{Andy}\INDEX[]{Andy} \chapter{two} \textbf{Beth}\INDEX[]{Beth} \chapter{three} \textbf{Carla}\INDEX[]{Carla} \chapter`{four}` \DEX[]{Andy} \DEX[]{Beth} .


\clearpage
\hypersetup{%
  linkcolor=backwardlinkcolor
}
\printindex


\end{document}
```

Comment: It's working except that that last command does not print the index!

Comment: @schremmer: I don't understand what you mean? Which last command? `\printindex`? I see the index in my output file

Comment: I had forgotten to re-enter the line for LatexMark! Sorry about that.

Comment: I spoke too soon. The above works fine but in the magnum opus it does not distinguish forward and backward. Also, it seems it does not like it when a referred word is in a table. Not sure though, no time to really check. If you want to, `Text-contents > 1.tex`, available at the same place, has a mini example and a table at the top and Preamble.sty has a fork.

Comment: It does not seem to like it either when the referred word is to be formatted as, e.g., `\DEX[zap]{\emph{zap}}` which works fine in the original `DEX`.

Comment: @schremmer: I told you more than once (I think) that you have constructed a fragile building with your code. I did not change a lot inside of `\DEX` apart from a page number check and then using `\hypersetup` ... this should not change anything apart from the link color

Comment: You did tell me and I was convinced even before that which is why in the MWE I always include at least the Heiko Oberdiek hack and some more. It is not my code as I couldn't write code to save my life and, as far as I know, there is no package that does what I think is the way of the future. Hopefully, someone will do it. In the meantime, what would you suggest?