# Math operator seeing as environment

Tags: math-operators

I always define my math operators by using `\DeclareMathOperator` from the  package `amsmath`. The problem is that let say I use my operator already defined as `\Op` then when I write the instruction `$\Op x^2$` it looks something like this:

[image]

But I want something like this:

[image]

Note: At first this doesn't look like a big deal because I can always write something like `$\Op(X^2)$`, but there are also times in which I'd like to simplify things like when I'm writhing something like:

[image]

In this last case I'd like to write something like `$\Op a_n$` instead of the full thing `$\langle a_n\rangle_{n=0}^\infty$`.

Also, so sorry if there's already an answer to this, I just couldn't find it.

Comment: those are two different results from `\Op`.  you can't use `\DeclareMathOperator` using a `*` to indicate an option, because that's already defined to determine whether to use limits.  i think you'd better define two different macros, one the operator, and the second with a different name to give the angle-bracket form.  (and is that `_{i=1}` or should it be `_{n=1}`?)

Comment: @barbarabeeton should be n=0, thanks for the comment. I also found a similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28042/how-to-declare-an-operator-with-automatic-argument-bracketing?rq=1

Comment: For the last case you should take a look at the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` series of commands, from `mathtools`, § 3.6 of the documentation.

Comment: ah -- it's always possible to count on egreg for good advice.  does that make this question a duplicate, as far as you've concerned?  if so, should probably close this one with a pointer to the other.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, I think so. That answer worked for me perfectly. If someone had a different approach he could add it there I suppose. Thank you.